# If anything but 0 and 1, return false

Tags: java, regex

I've got the following code which converts binary (as a string input) into decimal, and I'd like to give an error message if the input contains anything other than the strings `1` or `0`.

```
if(anything besides 0 or 1)
    System.out.println("Binary numbers may only contain 0 or 1!");
else
    System.out.println(Conversion(binary));
```

I'm pretty sure what I'm looking for is a regular expression, but after searching around, I'm more confused than when I started.

Comment: [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))?

Comment: `anything besides 0 or 1` → `!yourString.matches("[01]+")`

Comment: @devnull would that not limit the possible string input to ONLY "0" and "1"? What if I have a string of binary numbers such as "01011101", it would then return false because it's neither 0 nor 1. EDIT: Oh don't steal sp00m's solution c.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if you have any character in the string except 0 and 1:

```
yourString.matches("[^01]")
```

The solution proposed by spOOm

```
!yourString.matches("[01]+")
```

means `the string does not have any seuquence of 0 or 1`,
and that is not exactly what the question implies:

```
I'd like to give an error message if the input contains
anything other than the strings 1 or 0
```

Comment: That is indeed the solution I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is will match a string containing only 0 and 1's.

```
theString.matches("^[01]+$")
```

1. The character class [01] matches 0's or 1's
2. The + says match 1 or more of the proceeding character class (so 0 or more 0's or 1's)
3. The ^ and $ says that the entire string must match

Comment: That's not quite right, because "" will be also matched in this case. Please use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: Ahh yes I should have clarified if the OP wanted the empty string matched (I incorrectly assumed he did), will edit my answer!